# Why can't i assign a lambda to an untyped predicate reference? but can assign an initialized typed predicate reference to it?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, functional-interface

I noticed something strange while trying to create custom predicate references that are used based on a method argument type.

I have an object called  `AffiliateLinkSubset` and it has a boolean getter called isGeneral. When i try to do the following:

```
Predicate<?> partitionPredicate = AffiliateLinkSubset::isGeneral;
```

I get the error `non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`.

But when i assign the generic type `AffiliateLinkSubset` to the Predicate it works, this is nothing special.. What is special however is that the following also works:

```
Predicate<AffiliateLinkSubset> partitionPredicate = affiliateLinkSubset::isGeneral;
Predicate<?> test = partitionPredicate;
```

The IDE gives no error for this! Even though I am effectively assigning the same lambda to the untyped predicate test. How is this possible? And will the predicate work during runtime? I assume it will because during compilation all types are erased and replaced with type Object. This is why I don't understand why I can't assign an untyped predicate a lambda. Can anyone explain?

`AffiliateLinkSubset` is an abbreviation of the actual class, here it is:

```
import POJOs.PojoENUMS.LocalizedStorefront;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class AffiliateLinkSubsetForStatisticsCalculation {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private Double productValue;
    private boolean general;
    private Set<String> keywords;
    private Map<String, Boolean> booleanKeywords;
    private LocalizedStorefront localizedStorefront;

    public AffiliateLinkSubsetForStatisticsCalculation(Long id, String title, Double productValue, boolean general, Set<String> keywords, Map<String, Boolean> booleanKeywords, LocalizedStorefront localizedStorefront) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.productValue = productValue;
        this.general = general;
        this.keywords = keywords;
        this.booleanKeywords = booleanKeywords;
        this.localizedStorefront = localizedStorefront;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Double getProductValue() {
        return productValue;
    }

    public void setProductValue(Double productValue) {
        this.productValue = productValue;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public boolean isGeneral() {
        return general;
    }

    public void setGeneral(boolean general) {
        this.general = general;
    }

    public Set<String> getKeywords() {
        return keywords;
    }

    public void setKeywords(Set<String> keywords) {
        this.keywords = keywords;
    }

    public Map<String, Boolean> getBooleanKeywords() {
        return booleanKeywords;
    }

    public void setBooleanKeywords(Map<String, Boolean> booleanKeywords) {
        this.booleanKeywords = booleanKeywords;
    }

    public LocalizedStorefront getLocalizedStorefront() {
        return localizedStorefront;
    }

    public void setLocalizedStorefront(LocalizedStorefront localizedStorefront) {
        this.localizedStorefront = localizedStorefront;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the `AffiliateLinkSubset` class and it's method `isGeneral`, please.

Comment: none of the methods are static

Comment: @Maurice does `Predicate<?> p = ffiliateLinkSubset::isGeneral;` work?

Comment: @Lino its not a static context, this error is being thrown when the IDE doesn't have any other standard error message to show, it doesn't say anything about the nature of the actual error. `ffiliateLinkSubset::isGeneral` is a method reference, or a lambda abbreviation so to speak. See more info about it here: https://dzone.com/articles/java-lambda-expressions-vs

Comment: @Lino why would a change in reference name make things different? Predicate<?> p = affiliateLinkSubset::isGeneral; doesn't work either.

Comment: Incidentally, a `Predicate<?>` isn't terribly useful; the only argument you can pass to it is `null`. Did you maybe want a `Predicate<Object>`?

Comment: no i want this: Predicate<AffiliateLinkSubsetForStatisticsCalculation> partitionPredicate = AffiliateLinkSubsetForStatisticsCalculation::isGeneral;

Comment: Shouldn't **affiliateLinkSubset::isGeneral** be **AffiliateLinkSubset::isGeneral**, 
with an uppercase **A** at the start?

Comment: You are freely and casually using "lambda" as though it is just an alternative term for "method reference". It isn't. You should correct the title, body and tags of your post to properly reflect that you are using method references, and you are not using lambdas. As it stands your question does not show proper research effort.

Comment: @skomisa a method reference is an abbreviation of a lambda. The method reference is like a syntactic sugar of a lambda

Comment: @Maurice You can choose to _conceptually_ think of a method reference as syntactic sugar for a lambda expression, but [the code generated is not the same](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/302313/108656), and a method reference does not get "desugared" into a lambda. And it is just wrong to have "lambda" in the title, body and tags for this post when the code you provide is using method references, not lambdas. Referring to a method reference as a lambda is incorrect and false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly the `Predicate<?> predicate` cant work since the unknown type. Any of them will work:

```
Predicate<? extends AffiliateLinkSubset> predicate = AffiliateLinkSubset::isGeneral;
Predicate<AffiliateLinkSubset> predicate = AffiliateLinkSubset::isGeneral;
```

The method reference shortcut `AffiliateLinkSubset::isGeneral` is understood as `object -> object.isGeneral()` where `object` is a type of `AffiliateLinkSubset`. This is why the first predicate couldn't work, because of `<?>` which didn't defined the type of `AffiliateLinkSubset`. The `isGeneral()` method is not defined in `Object`.

Let's continue. If you type:

```
Predicate<?> partitionPredicate = object -> AffiliateLinkSubset.isGeneral();
```

This will not compile since you treat the class method `isGeneral()` the same way is it were a static one. For this you need an instance of a class which can call this method:

```
AffiliateLinkSubset affiliateLinkSubset = new AffiliateLinkSubset();
Predicate<?> partitionPredicate = object -> affiliateLinkSubset.isGeneral();
```

Now, `object` is an instance of `Object` and the result relies on the right side of the lambda which doesn't touch the `object` and doesn't matter the input, thus this might work as well:

```
Supplier<Boolean> supplier = () -> affiliateLinkSubset.isGeneral();
```

It makes not much sense so I guess the solution you really have been mentioned already:

```
Predicate<? extends AffiliateLinkSubset> predicate = AffiliateLinkSubset::isGeneral;
```

Comment: I can leave the second Predicate untyped (<?>) if i type the first predicate. I get no error when i assign the first predicate to the second untyped one, why is this so? Shouldn't the second Predicate assignment also have given an error?

Answer (score 1):

```
AffiliateLinkSubsetForStatisticsCalculation::isGeneral
```

means

```
(AffiliateLinkSubsetForStatisticsCalculation i) -> i.isGeneral()
```

while

```
affiliateLinkSubsetForStatisticsCalculationInstance::isGeneral
```

refers either to (1) an instance method `boolean isGeneral(Object o)` of `AffiliateLinkSubsetForStatisticsCalculation` or to (2) an instance method `boolean isGeneral()` of `Object`.

Since neither of those methods exists, you can write a method reference. But you could write a lambda:

```
Predicate<?> p = (Object i) -> affiliateLinkSubsetForStatisticsCalculationInstance.isGeneral();
```

*`AffiliateLinkSubsetForStatisticsCalculation` is the class name.
**`affiliateLinkSubsetForStatisticsCalculationInstance` is an instance of the class.

Comment: what do you mean with variable of the class, like an instance of the class?

Comment: good answer but it still doesn't answer the main question. Why can i assign a typed predicate to an untyped predicate reference? Is it because the wildcard ? can be translated to being Object and since my AffiliateSubset class is also an object in the end, it makes it possible to assign it because of passive casting? For instance, you can Always cast a String to an Object reference because a string is Always an object.

Comment: @Maurice, you are right, `Predicate<?>` stands for "a predicate of anything", and `Predicate<AffiliateLinkSubsetForStatisticsCalculation>` fits that